# SAP HANA function: Evaluate

Tags: mysql, sql, database, hana

Customer table has a list of customers with list of items.

We have received a list of items with the ranks. 
So we have to find out the customers ranks by summing up the ranks.

`Customer ID| Items | rank
  1         | 1     | 1 
  1         | 1     | 1 
  1         | 2     | 4
  1         | 2     | 4
  1         | 3     | 1`

desired out put

`CustomerID | rank
  1         | 6`

I am always confused when it comes to each customer. any help is much appreciated!

I am adding few tags, please excuse me if they are not  relevant!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For HANA the Query would look like this (with some test data):

```
create column table "CustomerItems"
("CustomerID" nvarchar(10),
 "Items"      nvarchar(10),
 "CRank"     integer
);


insert into "CustomerItems" ("CustomerID", "Items", "CRank") values ('1', '1', 1 );
insert into "CustomerItems" ("CustomerID", "Items", "CRank") values ('1', '1', 1 );
insert into "CustomerItems" ("CustomerID", "Items", "CRank") values ('1', '2', 4 );
insert into "CustomerItems" ("CustomerID", "Items", "CRank") values ('1', '2', 4 );
insert into "CustomerItems" ("CustomerID", "Items", "CRank") values ('2', '1', 3 );
insert into "CustomerItems" ("CustomerID", "Items", "CRank") values ('2', '1', 3 );
insert into "CustomerItems" ("CustomerID", "Items", "CRank") values ('2', '3', 5 );

select "CustomerID", Sum(distinct("CRank"))
  from "CustomerItems"
  group by "CustomerID"
  order by "CustomerID"
```

I would not use "Rank" as a column name. This is a [reserved word](https://help.sap.com/doc/f381aa9c4b99457fb3c6b53a2fd29c02/2.0.00/en-US/888f434c5e494d6c9af82bc5db854a14.html) (window functions) an can lead to confusions.

For MySQL just replace `create column table` with `create table` and the double quotes by backticks.

If this answers your question I would also recommend some introductory book or online tutorial on SQL.
If not, please provide more information, create table statement etc.

Edit after comment and changed test data:

If you want to sum up your "ranks" of distinct combinations of Customer/Item, try this one (for MySQL again backticks instead of double quote, and you have to give the subquery its own alias):

```
select "CustomerID", sum("CRank")
from 
(
select distinct "CustomerID", "Items", "CRank"
  from "CustomerItems"
)
  group by "CustomerID"
  order by "CustomerID"
```

Comment: Hi Christoph, Thanks for the answer. you have answered the question, but this doesn't satisfy when there is an additional item with the same rank as others. "I have updated the table in the question." I would definetly consider your recommendation of going through a introductory book.